# How to read a data file and insert data into a mysql database

Tags: mysql, insert

I am new to Java and I'm trying to insert data into a mysql database using a text file. My text file has 5 rows.  I have 3 SQL insert Queries.  Each query will insert 5 rows into the database.

Example queries are:

```sql
INSERT INTO `session` (`emp`, `SessionID`, `SessionDate`, `SessionStartTime`, 'SessionEndTime') VALUES (Tyler, NULL, ?, ?, ?);

INSERT INTO `session` (`emp`, `SessionID`, `SessionDate`, `SessionStartTime`,'SessionEndTime') VALUES (MAX, NULL, ?, ?, ?);

INSERT INTO `session` (`emp`, `SessionID`, `SessionDate`, `SessionStartTime`,'SessionEndTime') VALUES (James, NULL, ?, ?, ?);
```

Example text file:

[textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6FTZ.png)

Here is a snippet of my code.  I having problems with figuring out how to  read the text file and inserting it into the database. Note that the code only has one my queries.  I'm trying to get one query to work before adding the others.

I'm looking for some advice on reading the file and the prepared statements for the date, start time, and end time.

any suggestions?

```java
try 
    {
        //Create a mysql database connection

        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest";        
        String username = "root";      //Database Username          
        String password = "abcdefg";  //Database Password
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     //Load mysql jdbc driver        
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);  //Create Connection to DB   


     // mysql query to insert data into session table

        String query = " INSERT INTO `session` (`emp`, `SessionID`, 
        `SessionDate`, `SessionStartTime`) VALUES (Tyler, NULL, ?, ?, ?);     

        try { 
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(newFileReader("c:/sessionstime"));

            String line = ""; 

            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) 
               {
                try 
                   {

                      if (line != null) 
                         {
                            String[] array = line.split(",");
                            for(String result:array)
                               {


     // create mysql insert preparedstatement
          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

          preparedStmt.setDate   (1, sessiondate[0]);
          preparedStmt.setTime   (2, sessionstarttime[1]);
          preparedStmt.setTime   (3, sessionendtime[2]);
          preparedStmt.addBatch();



     // execute the preparedstatement
          preparedStmt.executeBatch();

     // close database connection     
          con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Got an exception!");
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Your INSERT statement specifies four columns, but you have five placeholders in the VALUES clause.

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake on my part.  The 5th column is there now.

Comment: The problem that I'm having a hard time understanding is the                       preparedStmt.setDate   (1, sessiondate[0]);
           preparedStmt.setTime   (2, sessionstarttime[1]);
           preparedStmt.setTime   (3, sessionendtime[2]);
           preparedStmt.addBatch();

Comment: I tried to clean up your code sample formatting. Verify its correctness. And learn to use the formatting commands such as `<!-- language: lang-java -->` when mixing languages (here, SQL & Java).